# problem with sqlite database query, the distinct query not working

Tags: database, xcode, select, sqlite, distinct

in my sqlite database, a table named image contains three fields label, url and index.
I wrote the following piece of code for fetching data from database: "SELECT DISTINCT(label), index from image;". In my table there is a label 'Cat' 3 times. According to this code the code must show only one 'Cat' from my database. But it won't working. It fetches all three 'Cat' label. Why it happens? please help me to find a possible solution. index field is different for all three 'Cat' labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DISTINCT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#distinct) keyword is not a function, it specifies that duplicate rows should be removed from the results:

> If the simple SELECT is a SELECT DISTINCT, then duplicate rows are
>   removed from the set of result rows before it is returned

What you are trying to accomplish probably requires you to group by label:

```
SELECT label, index FROM image GROUP BY label
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select label, index from image
where label in (select distinct label from image)
```